# Can I use "are being " + past participle?

Tags: passive-voice, progressive-aspect, present-continuous

Sentences with form "are being " + past tense

are they correct form of grammar. And what tense do they represent.

like:

> You are being missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a grammatically correct sentence in the Present Progressive tense. It uses the Passive Voice too.

It says that someone is actively missing you (wishes you were near them), but says nothing about who exactly is missing you.

Transforming it into the Active Voice, we may get the following sentence:

> [We are] missing you.

What can vary is the part in the brackets: it depends on who exactly *is missing* the person. It can me [I am], [she is], [he is], [they are] etc.

The word **missed** is not in the Past Tense in your example. It is in the [Past Participle](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#Past_participles) form. It has been put into this form to help form the Passive Voice construction, which consists of the verb *to be* + *Past Participle*.

Your sentence without the Progressive aspect will look like this:

> You are missed. (BE + Past Participle = Passive Voice)

Then we add *being* to form the Progressive Aspect, in order to highlight the fact that the process of *missing you* is actively happening right now, that someone is actively missing you at this moment:

> You are *being* missed. (Passive Voice + *being* to form the Progressive Aspect)

Comment: So this is a past participle form. And is being missed is correct form of grammar.

Comment: @pritkalra: Yes. The word **being** helps to form the progressive aspect, used to stress the fact that a continuous process is taking place right now.

Comment: Thanks Man. And what are the verbs used in this sentence ?

Comment: @pritkalra: the only full-fledged verb in your sentence is **are**. The word *being* is a present participle, the word *missed* is a past participle. They have some verbal characteristics but are not, strictly speaking, verbs.

Comment: @pritkalra: you're welcome!

Comment: *Miss* is usually stative, so people usually say "We miss you" in the simple present,  not "We're missing you".  It's not entirely impossible to use it dynamically, so the latter is possible too, though less common.  And you might, very rarely, find an example like the OP's which is passive + progressive.  But it's rare enough that I couldn't find any in any corpora I checked―I only found false positives in my searches.  So I think it might be worth pointing out that people generally don't use *miss* this way.