# What kind of sentence it is

Tags: passive-voice, exam-questions

Consider following sentence to be transformed into passive voice. Here what which verb out of 'like' and 'telling' I should consider ti be changed into v3 foRm in passive voice. Same confusion with object.Only thing on which I am sure, is subject which is 'I' here. I am confused with all the four options given in the question.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use "are being " + past participle?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41666/can-i-use-are-being-past-participle)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are pretty confusing sentences. The first thing to do is figure out what the main active verb is in the original sentence. In this case, it's ***telling***, the continuous form of "to tell." Since you're looking for passive, you need to be able to recognize what the passive, continuous form of ***telling*** looks like. If you consult your textbook, the answer is ***being told***.

In this example, there's only one sentence that actually contains a passive verb, and yes, it's ***being told***. Sentence #2.

Another helpful hint. Try not to let repeated phrases interfere with seeing the sentences properly. In this example, every option contains ***I don't like*** and ***what to do***. If you remove those phrases from every option (you could even cross them out), there are only a few words left in each sentence that you need to consider.

Comment: Shouldn't the active verb be 'like' because this is the verb associated with the subject 'I'. Otherwise how can I come to conclusion that 'telling' is the main verb to be converted to passive form ?